# Programmatically replacing linked server references with local database references in SQL Server stored procs?

Tags: sql, sql-server, metadata

As a part of a scripted procedure I'm trying to *programmatically* update references to linked servers in stored procs. We have several references like this:-

```
SELECT foo, bar
FROM [Server].[Database].dbo.[Table]
```

Which I would like to translate to:-

```
SELECT foo, bar
FROM [Database].dbo.[Table]
```

I would like to do this entirely programmatically in a 'fire and forget' script across several databases.

The idea I have right now is to use metadata to find references to linked tables, read the text of each sp from metadata again, adjust each sp's text, then shove each block of updated text into an exec statement to rebuild 'em one-by-one.

I do wonder whether this will be a humongous pain however, so does anybody have any better ideas? I am open to using powershell if that could provide a better solution.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: fyi: the `sqlserver*` tags were re-named site wide.  Please use 'sql-server' going forward.

Comment: Ah thanks. Wasn't aware (haven't been on here for a while...!)

Answer (score 1):

Hopefully I am understanding the questions, but rather than removing or replacing [Server], I suggest one of two approaches:

- Option 1: Don't change any of the
  SPs. Instead, update the linked
  server configuration to point a
  different database, even the local
  box.
- Option 2: Don't change any of the
  SPs. Instead, start using SQL Server
  Aliases. SQL Server Aliases are
  managed via the CliConfig utility and
  are ultimately stored in the
  registry.  Thus, they can be applied
  manually or via .reg script.
  Basically, the SQL Server Alias
  deciphers the server (along with
  port) which is being referenced. If
  you update the link server
  configuration to reference the SQL
  Server Alias rather than a specific
  server, you can point your procedures
  to different server (even the local server) whenever you
  would like.

I hope it helps.

Comment: The problem with updating the linked servers to point at the local box (which is necessary in this case) is that there are issues with loopback linked servers, mainly with writing data in the same query as reading from the linked server, something I need to do.

Aliases don't fix it as sql server doesn't bother checking aliases for linked servers (afaik).

Answer (score 1):

Your approach is the easiest, frankly. I had a similar issue earlier this year

- Read sys.sql_modules
- REPLACE the linked server text and CREATE -> ALTER
- EXEC (@Result)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a script to find all procs/functions/views that reference linked servers on a SQL 2005 instance - might be useful too:

```
USE master
GO
SET NOCOUNT ON;

--------------------------------------------------------------------
-- Test linked server connections
--------------------------------------------------------------------
BEGIN TRY   DROP TABLE #Svrs;   END TRY BEGIN CATCH END CATCH;

CREATE TABLE #Svrs
(
    [Server]                nvarchar(max),
    [CanConnectAsDefault]   bit
);

DECLARE @ServerName nvarchar(max), @RetVal int;

DECLARE Svrs CURSOR FAST_FORWARD READ_ONLY
FOR
    SELECT  ServerName = S.name
    FROM    sys.servers S;

OPEN Svrs;
FETCH NEXT FROM Svrs INTO @ServerName;
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    BEGIN TRY
        EXEC @RetVal = sys.sp_testlinkedserver @ServerName;
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        SET @RetVal = sign(@@error);
    END CATCH;

    INSERT INTO #Svrs 
    SELECT  @ServerName 
        ,   CASE WHEN @RetVal = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END;

    FETCH NEXT FROM Svrs INTO @ServerName;
END;
CLOSE Svrs;
DEALLOCATE Svrs;

SELECT * FROM #Svrs
DROP TABLE #Svrs;
GO

--------------------------------------------------------------------
-- Report linked server references
--------------------------------------------------------------------
BEGIN TRY   DROP TABLE #Refs;   END TRY BEGIN CATCH END CATCH;

CREATE TABLE #Refs
(
    [Server]    nvarchar(max),
    [Database]  nvarchar(max),
    [Schema]    nvarchar(max),
    [Object]    nvarchar(max),
    [Type]      nvarchar(max)
);

DECLARE @DatabaseName nvarchar(max), @ServerName nvarchar(max), @SQL nvarchar(max);
DECLARE Refs CURSOR FAST_FORWARD READ_ONLY
FOR
    SELECT  DatabaseName = D.name 
        ,   ServerName = S.name
    --  ,   ServerProvider = S.provider
    --  ,   ServerSource = S.data_source
    FROM    sys.databases D 
            CROSS JOIN sys.servers S
    WHERE D.name NOT IN ('master', 'tempdb', 'model', 'msdb', 'ReportServer', 'ReportServerTempDB');

OPEN Refs;
FETCH NEXT FROM Refs INTO @DatabaseName, @ServerName;
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    SET @SQL = 'USE [' + @DatabaseName + '];                
                INSERT INTO #Refs 
                SELECT DISTINCT ''' + @ServerName + ''', ''' + @DatabaseName + ''', S.[name], O.[name], O.type_desc 
                FROM    syscomments C
                        INNER JOIN sys.objects O ON C.id = O.[object_id]
                        LEFT JOIN sys.schemas S ON S.[schema_id] = O.[schema_id]
                WHERE   C.[TEXT] LIKE ''%[ ,~[( '''']' + @ServerName + '[ .,~])'''' ]%'' ESCAPE ''~'';'

    PRINT 'Looking for ' + @ServerName + ' refs in ' + @DatabaseName -- + ': ' + @SQL;

    EXEC sp_executesql @SQL;

    FETCH NEXT FROM Refs INTO @DatabaseName, @ServerName;
END
CLOSE Refs;
DEALLOCATE Refs;

SELECT * FROM #Refs
DROP TABLE #Refs;
GO

--------------------------------------------------------------------
SET NOCOUNT OFF;
GO
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not going to be a good idea for a production environment, but if you need a loopback linked server for dev purposes [this](https://web.archive.org/web/20190619203025/http://geekswithblogs.net/urig/archive/2006/03/23/73132.aspx) worked for me:

```
EXEC sp_addlinkedserver @server = N'name_for_linked_server',
    @srvproduct = N' ',
    @provider = N'SQLNCLI', 
    @datasrc = N'name_of_my_sqlserver_instance', 
    @catalog = N'name_of_database'
```